# Maximal length of a finite real sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Suppose that $(a_n)_{1 \le n \le N}$ is a finite sequence of reals such that the sum of any 7 consecutive terms is (strictly) negative and the sum of any 11 consecutive terms is (strictly) positive.

What is the maximal length of this finite sequence of reals?

*I tried creating finite sequences having the given property. I succeeded in creating a sequence of 16 terms. Namely $5,5,-13,5,5,5,-13,5,5,-13,5,5,5,-13,5,5$... but wasn't able to do more.*

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: @mike239x I tried creating finite sequences having the given property. I succeeded in creating a sequence of 16 terms. Namely $5,5,-13,5,5,5,-13,5,5,-13,5,5,5,-13,5,5$... but wasn't able to do more.

Comment: That is pretty good. Try proving that sequance of 17 terms is impossible.

Comment: Where is this question from?

Comment: @M.Winter It was problem 2 on the first day of the 1977 IMO. 16 is best possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume there is a sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_{17})$ satisfying the restrictions. Then take all the inequalities you can get:
$$\{a_i+\ldots+a_{i+6} < 0\}_{i \in [11]}$$
$$\{0 < a_i+\ldots+a_{i+10}\}_{i \in [7]}$$
(here $[n]$ stays for $\{1,\ldots,n\}$).

Add all these inequalities together, you will get $0 < 0$.

So a sequence of 17 terms is impossible (and any sequence with more elements is impossible as well).

Comment: What is the length of the sequence be 16 or less?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz It is given in the question...

Comment: Sorry...It was a type... i meant $if$ instead of $is$....

Answer (score 0):

$x_1+\dots+x_7<0$ and $x_8+\dots+x_{14}<0$, so $x_1+\dots+x_{14}<0$. But $x_4+\dots+x_{14}>0$, so $x_1+x_2+x_3<0$.

$x_5+\dots+x_{11}<0$ and $x_1+\dots+x_{11}>0$, so $x_4>0$. From there is it easy to get a contradiction if you have 17 terms.